# Qual è il significato di "chiabotto"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Se Tobia non m’avesse tenuto cosí a catena, sarei andato qualche giorno a trovarlo dov’era da servitore. Stava passato il pilone del Chiarle, a un’ora da noi, con due vecchi particolari, uomo e donna, in un **chiabotto** di due stanze e la stalla e un lenzuolo di terra; però faceva andare avanti tutto lui.

Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è un "chiabotto"?
Non ho trovato questo vocabolo in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine piemontese?

Comment: Ho trovato questa [traduzione de *La malora* al castigliano](https://books.google.es/books?id=r8WXfwqTeb0C&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=chiabotto+fenoglio&source=bl&ots=NMmnZ92oQm&sig=vuF473r9xmByFi_d9ldcjUDvpII&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5lJe22e_bAhXGbxQKHSIoAuUQ6AEIGDAF#v=onepage&q=chiabotto%20fenoglio&f=false). Nella introduzione si afferma che di tratta di un termine comune della lingua regionale del nord Italia e che ha il significato di "choza" in spagnolo, cioè, "capanna".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il termine da ricercare è [ciabot](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciab%C3%B2t) :

> Il ciabòt è un piccolo fabbricato caratteristico dei vigneti
>   piemontesi che nasce da un insieme di necessità legate al lavoro della
>   viticoltura.

Nel [Vocabolario piemontese-italiano del sacerdote Michele Ponza](http://www.piemunteis.it/liber-liber/vocabolario-piemontese-italiano-di-michele-ponza) alla voce ciabot si può leggere a pagina 188:

> *Ciabot, n*, casupola, casuccia, casetta da campagna.

In un altro dizionario sempre sullo stesso sito, sotto Home>>DEP

> ciabot - 
> casa rustica sostantivo maschile 
>  forme flesse: ciabot,
>   ciabot

Nel dialetto Ligure, ad esempio, ha il significato di capanna per gli attrezzi, di solito di legno.

Comment: Quindi, secondo il [Vocabolario piemontese-italiano del sacerdote Michele Ponza](http://www.piemunteis.it/liber-liber/vocabolario-piemontese-italiano-di-michele-ponza) il significato è: «casupola, casuccia, casetta da campagna.»

Comment: Il significato è esattamente quello.

Comment: Ti andrebbe di aggiungere la definizione del vocabolario Ponza alla risposta? Forse non è una meraviglia, ma mi sembra che così si possa avere qualcosa un po' più completo.

Comment: @Charo Aggiunta definizione alla risposta.

Comment: Scusa, ma dove hai trovato la prima definizione?

Comment: In **Home**>>**DEP**. C'è un campo in cui puoi scrivere il termine piemontese e ti vengono suggerite delle alternative. Se scrivi ciabot ti esce la prima definizione

Comment: L'ho visto, grazie: si tratta del Dizionario Elettronico Piemontese (http://www.piemunteis.it/dep/dizionario.dep), che non è la stessa cosa del Vocabolario piemontese-italiano di Michele Ponza. Infatti, ho scoperto che, su questo sito, ci sono parecchi dizionari di piemontese:

Comment: http://www.piemunteis.it/liber-liber/vocabolario-piemontese-del-medico-maurizio-pipino, http://www.piemunteis.it/liber-liber/dictionnaire-portatif-piemontais-francais,  http://www.piemunteis.it/liber-liber/dizionario-piemontese-italiano-latino-e-francese, http://www.piemunteis.it/liber-liber/nuovo-dizionario-piemontese-italiano, http://www.piemunteis.it/liber-liber/gran-dizionario-piemontese-italiano

Comment: Ulteriori miglioramenti alla risposta

Comment: Quindi  Chiabotto come cognome deriva da quel significato. Infatti la nota Cristina Chiabotto se non sbaglio è piemontese. https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristina_Chiabotto